# Strange behavior of ModelMapper used in Spring with HibernateTemplate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, modelmapper

I have really strange behavior of ModelMapper framework combined with Spring and Hibernate 4. And after 2 days of searching through SO I still a little bit confused and can't figure out the reason of such strange behavior.

I have 3 classes: class A, class B and User class.

User class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class User implements UserDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    private String id;

...
}
```

Class B:

```
@Entity
@Audited
@Table
@Data
@Builder
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class B implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    private String id;

...

    @Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(/*some join definition*/)
    private Set<A> a;
}
```

Class A:

```
@Entity
@Audited
@Table
@Data
@Builder
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class A implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    private String id;

    ...
    @Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    @Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(/*some join definition*/)
    private Set<User> subscribers;
}
```

In my controller I have below code:

```
List<B> bObjects = bService.findAll();
return modelMapper.map(bObjects, new TypeToken<List<BDto>>() {
}.getType());
```

And the problem is in first run query after database was dropped and recreated. 
I drop database and run my application, and add new objects of A and B class. And then, when I try to list all objects that are in my table, ModelMapper returns null in place of User class object. Every first run it returns null. When I restart application users are mapped properly. Moreover, when I use UserController to return all users, all users returned corectly and al properties are properly mapped. 
More itnerresting, that objects of class B contain relationship of class A and these object of class A are returned properly even in first run of Application.

These entities are loaded Eagerly, so hibernate must load it. 
When I use standard converter to convert A to ADto everything works fine. 
Converter contains hardcoded line:

```
aDtoObject.setUserDto(aObject.getUser());
```

I insert default users in my ApplicationStartUp class.

My hibernate config properties:

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
hibernate.showSql=false
hibernate.formatSql=false
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
hibernate.jdbc.batchSize=100
hibernate.orderInserts=true
hibernate.orderUpdates=true
hibernate.jdbc.batchVersionedData=true
hibernate.ejb.event.post-insert = org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PostInsertEventListener,org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener
hibernate.ejb.event.post-update = org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PostUpdateEventListener,org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener
hibernate.ejb.event.post-delete = org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PostDeleteEventListener,org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener
hibernate.ejb.event.pre-collection-update = org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener
hibernate.ejb.event.pre-collection-remove = org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener
hibernate.ejb.event.post-collection-recreate = org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener
```

ModelMapper config:

```
@Configuration
public class ModelMapperConfig {

    @Bean
    public ModelMapper strictModelMapper() {
        ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
        modelMapper.getConfiguration().setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.STANDARD);
        return modelMapper;
    }
}
```

POM:

```
        <spring-version>4.2.4.RELEASE</spring-version>
        <hibernate-version>4.3.8.Final</hibernate-version>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
        <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
        <version>0.7.5</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate-version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate-version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Can anybody help me to figure it out? Any ideas what can I check and what can be a reason to such strange behavior?

P.S. whant to udnerline just with User class. Other classes are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to add mappings to your model mapper, incase you have not done that in your configuration class -

```
modelMapper.addMappings(new OutputMapper());
```

You are retrieving configuration when you define model mapper but consider overriding the configure() method of PropertyMap to individually map your attributes:

```
class OutputMapper extends PropertyMap<AData, Output> {

   @Override
   protected void configure(){

     map().setABCD(source.getABCD());

   }
}
```